# Bootstrap Accordion ScrollTop with Fixed Menu Header

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, accordion, scrolltop, menubar

I would really appreciate if someone could further explain to me this.
My problem is, when I click the accordion->it will slide to the Top but it's almost HALF the panel body.
Here's the sample link that I've modified. Credits and thanks to Mr. Yeco and Mr. Zessx.
Click here [Jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/zessx/R6EAW/12/)!

Would adding a margin-top a good idea?

```
#accordion .panel-heading {
    margin-top: 50px;
}
```

Comment: I didn't quite get the problem, I tried with chrome and IE, added some text, the accordion ajdusts its height each time correctly according to the height of the contents, or shows the 3 toggles if all are collapsed. Do you mean to have a fixed height?

Comment: Thanks for your response Mr. Mirko. Sorry but I posted the wrong link. Here's what I'm working on.. [HERE](http://jsfiddle.net/elaidomino/qmg61vxe/2/)

Comment: ok, I saw that when I expand the accordion it scrolls to the header of the expanded section, but I still don't get the problem. Could you elaborate a bit more what you mean by 'it will slide to the Top but it's almost HALF the panel body'?